SWIG function returning reference
I want to run SWIG on the following C++ structure :
        struct TestAlias
        {
            TestAlias(double a1, double a2, double a3) : angle1(a1), angle2(a2), angle3(a3) {}

            double angle1;
            double angle2;
            double angle3;

            double& psi = angle1;
            double& theta = angle2;
            double& phi = angle3;
        };

and then use it like this in Python :
        test_alias = TestAlias(1.1, 22.22, 333.333)
        test_alias.psi = 4444.4444
        print('testAlias = (%r, %r, %r)' % (test_alias.psi, test_alias.theta, test_alias.phi))

In my ".i" file, I had to use %apply double& INOUT { double& psi }; to make test_alias.psi = 4444.4444 work.
But now, the result of 'print' is : testAlias = (<Swig Object of type 'double *' at 0x0000024CDB1B6A80>, <Swig Object of type 'double *' at 0x0000024CDB1B6AE0>, <Swig Object of type 'double *' at 0x0000024CDB1B6B10>)
I would have expected : testAlias = (4444.4444, 22.22,333.333)
How could I achieve this?

You need to create a custom string representation, read about __str__ and __repr__. You don't have to do it with SWIG in C/C++ - you can do it entirely in Python if you are more comfortable. The object will remain a SWIG object but your print will retrieve the custom string representation.
